# "VC: Tinymce error! Compatibility problem with other plugins." в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

При открытии редактора текстового блока появляется html код. Исчез визивиг.

В консоли выводится ошибка "VC: Tinymce error! Compatibility problem with other plugins.". Поочередно деактивировал все активные плагины - результата успешного нет

Comment: Значит, проблема в теме. В неё, похоже, встроен VIsual Composer (VC) - его сообщение вы и видите.

Comment: Как с этой проблемой бороться?

Comment: Скорее всего, никак. Тема откуда взята? Купленная? Свежая?